# Retrieving column names with column values in sqlite using cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I want to display column names with column values in the Listview using cursor.
My present code shows only the column values.

```
public void openAndQueryDatabase() {

    db = openOrCreateDatabase( "mydatabase.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY , null ); 

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+ table + " where name='"+ name + "'",  null);


    int count = cursor.getColumnCount();

    if (cursor!=null )
    { 

        if  (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do 
            {
                 for (int i =0 ; i< count; i++)
                {
                String data = cursor.getString(i);
                details.add(data);
                }
            } 
            while (cursor.moveToNext()); 
        } 

         }
}
```

Comment: use cursor.getColumnName(columnIndex)

Comment: You don't really need to do a rawquery, you could just use the wrapper methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you should use hashmap

```
for (int i =0 ; i< count; i++)
{
    String data = cursor.getString(i);
    String column_name = cursor.getColumnName(i);

    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put("column_value",data);
    map.put("column_name",column_name);

    details.add(map); //change the type of details from ArrayList<String> to arrayList<HashMap<String,String>>
}
```

Comment: you should edit your post instead of add another answer

Comment: this site allows to answer more than once. Right? therefore i did that.

Answer (score 2):

Use `getColumnName(int columnIndex)` to get the name of the row for a given index.

Comment: one liner: DatabaseUtils.cursorRowToContentValues

Answer (score 1):

**Use this.**

```
 for (int i =0 ; i< count; i++)
  {
      String data = cursor.getString(i);
      String column_name = cursor.getColumName(i);
      details.add(data);
  }
```

Comment: This will add only column values to the listview. How to display both of them together?

Answer (score 0):

Simply retrieve `String` array with names like that:

`cursor.getColumnNames()`